# If I define methods on the prototype, how do I call them in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, class, constructor

I understand that it is good practice to assign methods directly to a class' prototype so that they are not redefined every time the function is called.

```
var A = function () {
    this.prop = "A property";
}
A.prototype.method = function () {
    return "A method";
}
```

Say I want to call a method defined in this way in the constructor. Is this possible?

```
var A = function (options) {
    initialize(options); // initialize is undefined.
}
A.prototype.initialize = function (options) {
    // do something with options.
}
```

Creating a stub method inside the constructor doesn't work because it gets called instead of the prototype's version of the function. The only way I have been able to get this to work is to reference the function via bracket syntax `this["initialize"]()` which seems pretty inelegant.

```
var A = function (options) {
    this["initialize"](options); // function isn't defined yet but will be soon!
}
A.prototype.initialize = function (options) {
    // do something with options.
}
```

This seems pretty janky and would probably not be the most optimal way to call this function. **Is there another way or am I missing something?**

Comment: By the way, my specific case is that I'm trying to create a constructor that takes an options argument and processes the options by calling instance methods with the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last way is correct, but you don't need the quotes.

```
var A = function (options) {
    this.initialize(options); 
};
A.prototype.initialize = function (options) {
    // do something with options.
};
```

Assuming `A` is invoked as a constructor, `this` is a reference to the new object being constructed, and its prototype chain is already established, so it already has access to the `initialize` method.

Of course there's no requirement that `initialize` be prototyped. If it's not intended to be called more than once, then it may make more sense to define it as a stand alone function.

```
var A = function (options) {
    initialize(this, options); 
};
function initialize (obj, options) {
    // do something with options.
};
```

or you could just put the initialization code right in the constructor function.

Comment: +1 for the edit - I was trying to come up with a way to put that into a comment.

Comment: Ok. Your explanation makes perfect sense when I think of how this refers to the new instance. It just feels so dirty since I'm used to coding in more strongly-typed languages. But I guess I'll have to get over it.